# Android Eclipse resource not found on new install

Tags: android, eclipse

I believe that this is a set up issue not so much as a coding one.  I have a project that works just fine on another computer. I import my project into a fresh install and workspace on a different machine and I get the following error.  I have tried 2 similar projects and get the exact same issue with the same resource ID.

I have deleted and re-installed the Google Play Services Lib and the projects.  Also I tried cleaning the projects and deleting the R.java files and rebuilding.

When I try to search the workspace for the resource ID I come up blank.

Both the working machine and this one are using Juno eclipse.  The working machine is a windows 7 while the non working is 8.1.

Any help will be taken happily.

```
 10-05 21:28:26.709: E/AndroidRuntime(5034): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    10-05 21:28:26.709: E/AndroidRuntime(5034): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.package.TabsFragmentActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: 
Unable to find resource ID #0x7f05006f
    10-05 21:28:26.709: E/AndroidRuntime(5034):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2100)
    10-05 21:28:26.709: E/AndroidRuntime(5034):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2125)
    10-05 21:28:26.709: E/AndroidRuntime(5034):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
    10-05 21:28:26.709: E/AndroidRuntime(5034):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1227)
    10-05 21:28:26.709: E/AndroidRuntime(5034):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    10-05 21:28:26.709: E/AndroidRuntime(5034):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    10-05 21:28:26.709: E/AndroidRuntime(5034):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
    10-05 21:28:26.709: E/AndroidRuntime(5034):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    10-05 21:28:26.709: E/AndroidRuntime(5034):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    10-05 21:28:26.709: E/AndroidRuntime(5034):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1008)
    10-05 21:28:26.709: E/AndroidRuntime(5034):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:775)
    10-05 21:28:26.709: E/AndroidRuntime(5034):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    10-05 21:28:26.709: E/AndroidRuntime(5034): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Unable to find resource ID #0x7f05006f
    10-05 21:28:26.709: E/AndroidRuntime(5034):     at android.content.res.Resources.getResourceName(Resources.java:1661)
    10-05 21:28:26.709: E/AndroidRuntime(5034):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:919)
    10-05 21:28:26.709: E/AndroidRuntime(5034):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
    10-05 21:28:26.709: E/AndroidRuntime(5034):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
    10-05 21:28:26.709: E/AndroidRuntime(5034):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1467)
    10-05 21:28:26.709: E/AndroidRuntime(5034):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:570)
    10-05 21:28:26.709: E/AndroidRuntime(5034):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1178)
    10-05 21:28:26.709: E/AndroidRuntime(5034):     at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5216)
    10-05 21:28:26.709: E/AndroidRuntime(5034):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2073)
    10-05 21:28:26.709: E/AndroidRuntime(5034):     ... 11 more
```

[image]

Comment: Do you have the support library installed on the new machine and correctly referenced from your project?

Comment: Yes I believe I do.  I added a pic for reference and its in the workspace.

Comment: what are the differences between win7 and win8 systems, same java version ? same install locations ? any differences at all...

Comment: while the folder is different the relative locations of the sdk,play services, and eclipse are the same.